# Tikz style which can be used via \tikzset to disable text

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, nodes

I am looking for a `\tikzset` with which I can *disable* text from rendering. With a `\draw` I can say `draw=none`, as in (2), but is there something equivlaent to `text=none` I can use to disable the text as well.

The feeble attempt of `text=white` won't quite do as it fails for the case where the text was over some other part of the picture as in (3).

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{Line Draw Style/.style={ultra thick, gray}}
\tikzset{Text Style/.style={}}

\newcommand*{\MyTikzPicture}[1] {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [draw=green, ultra thick] (1,0) -- (2,0); % Should only be visible in (2)
        \draw [ultra thick, Line Draw Style] (0,0) -- (3,0) 
            node [pos=0.5, ultra thick, text=black, Text Style] {$A$}
            node [pos=0, left, text=black] {(#1)};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
    \MyTikzPicture{1}

\begingroup
    \tikzset{Line Draw Style/.style={draw=none}}%
    \tikzset{Text Style/.style={text=blue, font=\bfseries}}%
    \MyTikzPicture{2}
\endgroup

\begingroup
    \tikzset{Line Draw Style/.style={draw=red}}%
    \tikzset{Text Style/.style={text=white}}% <--- What can I do here to disable the text
    \MyTikzPicture{3}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dammm, seems like `text opacity=0` does what I am looking for. Not sure why I can't think of these _before_ going thru the effort of posting a question!! I'll add an answer in a while if no one else feels like writing it or has a better solution.

Comment: What do you mean with "disable"? The `text opacity` option sets the rendering to zero (not the same as disabling). `node contents=` disables content (and is not perfectly safe) but still renders the text (as in: the actual node has its minimum size because there is no text). Disabling the rendering for me means the same as `\phantom{<node content>}`. For disabling the whole node, you can just add `shape=coordinate`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: By "disable" I meant a setting I can apply via `\tikzset` which does not output the text. See case `(3)` where the text overlays on the line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from `text opacity`, you can use `node contents`

```
\newcommand*{\MyTikzPicture}[1] {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [draw=green, ultra thick] (1,0) -- (2,0); % Should only be visible in (2)
        \draw [ultra thick, Line Draw Style] (0,0) -- (3,0)
            node [pos=0.5, ultra thick, text=black, node contents={$A$}, Text Style] {} %%<-- here
            node [pos=0, left, text=black] {(#1)};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

And when you don't need text, over write the content to be empty with

```
\tikzset{Text Style/.style={node contents={}}}% <--- What can I do here to disable the text
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{Line Draw Style/.style={ultra thick, gray}}
\tikzset{Text Style/.style={}}

\newcommand*{\MyTikzPicture}[1] {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [draw=green, ultra thick] (1,0) -- (2,0); % Should only be visible in (2)
        \draw [ultra thick, Line Draw Style] (0,0) -- (3,0)
            node [pos=0.5, ultra thick, text=black, node contents={$A$}, Text Style] {}
            node [pos=0, left, text=black] {(#1)};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
    \MyTikzPicture{1}

\begingroup
    \tikzset{Line Draw Style/.style={draw=none}}%
    \tikzset{Text Style/.style={text=blue, font=\bfseries}}%
    \MyTikzPicture{2}
\endgroup

\begingroup
    \tikzset{Line Draw Style/.style={draw=red}}%
    \tikzset{Text Style/.style={node contents={}}}% <--- What can I do here to disable the text
    \MyTikzPicture{3}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]